# php xslt transformation always adds xmlns=""

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

Somehow my xslt transformation with php always adds `xmlns=""` as an attribute to all root elements. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Yes. Give them the proper xmlns value.

Answer (score 3):

In your XSLT try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="#default">
```

Comment: thanks, however switching to xsl:element seems to have solved my problem also ... guess I really need to do some reading ;)